# Docker-Symfony bin/console commands

Tags: symfony, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-17.10

I have symfony 3.4.6 installed on my ubuntu 1 machine. I have docker installed too, so I run: `docker-compose up -d`, then I entered the docker container and I wanted to make a cache clear. Here was the result:
Any ideas?

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
You have requested a non-existent parameter "api_doc_user_password".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are variables in the distribute file app/config/parameters.yml.dist that don't exist in the yml file that is app/config/parameters.yml. In this case "api_doc_user_password" was the variable.
We can copy this variable and its value to parameters.yml if we don't care about its dummy value.
We can also run composer install and it will be auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a code consistency check that is done when you do cache:clear. Somewhere in your code, you use an "api_doc_user_password" parameter that symfony does not know.